# What to do when shutdown stops because of efibootmgr? (efibootmgr Tainted)

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, shutdown, efibootmgr

Xubuntu 14.04

Before the last shutdown, I went about removing the Windows Boot Manager entry from the boot list as usual:

```
 sudo efibootmgr -b 0001 -B
```

After that, I wanted to look at the list as usual:

```
 sudo efibootmgr
```

Nothing happened. In fact, the PC froze up. Well, upon reboot everything was fine. It booted straight into Xubuntu. Then upon shutdown, it did not work properly. It said something about efibootmgr tainted. Here is the line from the log (`/var/log/kern.log`) and some more:

```
May 24 15:30:31 yolobox kernel: [   51.924921] CPU: 2 PID: 2348 Comm: efibootmgr Tainted: G        W     3.13.0-53-generic #89-Ubuntu
May 24 15:30:31 yolobox kernel: [   51.924969] Hardware name: To Be Filled By O.E.M. To Be Filled By O.E.M./H67M, BIOS P2.10 04/27/2012
May 24 15:30:31 yolobox kernel: [   51.925018] task: ffff88020f503000 ti: ffff8800c3f9a000 task.ti: ffff8800c3f9a000
May 24 15:30:31 yolobox kernel: [   51.925058] RIP: 0010:[<fffffffee4e1d8ae>]  [<fffffffee4e1d8ae>] 0xfffffffee4e1d8ae
May 24 15:30:31 yolobox kernel: [   51.925102] RSP: 0018:ffff8800c3f9bad0  EFLAGS: 00010046
```

Could someone please explain happened? How can I fix this? (I never had this before.)

Comment: What is the problem? There are no errors in the log. Just run "sudo update-grub" to fix, if you removed something wrong.